# attach a selected dropdown value to a variable and reuse it in html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var productStoreId = $('#productStoreId').val(); //productStoreId on change event
</script>

<select name="productStoreId" id="productStoreId">
    <option value='' selected="selected">Select Location</option>
    <#list productStoreList as store>
        <option value='${store.productStoreId}'>${store.storeName}</option>
    </#list>
</select>

<#assign AvblCrseList=prodStoreCoursesMap.get(${productStoreId})>// but productStoreId is undefined here.
```

I want productStoreId in a variable, because I have a map "prodStoreCoursesMap". I have to access it using the key productStoreId.

I want to access a map using the variable in the script tag as a key in the code in html/ftl.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var productStoreId = $('#productStoreId').val(); // productStoreId on change event
</script>
```

This will only work at launch but won't update as you select from the dropdown.

Try this:

```
var productId;

$('#productStoreId').on('change', function(){
    productId = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I got productId in script tag. How do I use this variable in html tag to access a map with productId as key. Is it possible

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about what do you mean by "user in html tag" ? can you provide the code of the "map" you keep referring to?

Comment: <form id="form-2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<@ofbizUrl>CreateNewApplication</@ofbizUrl>">
                    <div id="wizard-2">
                     <h3>Location & Course Type</h3>
                        <section><#assign AvblCrseList=prodStoreCoursesMap.get(${productStoreId})>
                          <fieldset></fieldset>
                        </section> // prodStoreCoursesMap is the map I am getting from context

Comment: you seem to be using some other language to render that. how about create a demo of the final page html here ( http://jsfiddle.net/ )